# Асинхронная многопоточность

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность

```
using System;
using log4net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace dotNetGameServer.Models.Controllers
{
    public static class GameTimeController
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public static async Task InitialiseAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProviderGameMaster)
        {
            serviceProvider = serviceProviderGameMaster;

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync);
        }

        private static async Task TickTimeElapsedAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Log.Info("Tick...");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я думал await `Task.Factory.StartNew` запускает новую задачу, а не поток. Как не как, в отладке мне выводит что строка `Tick...` отображается в разных потоках. То 4, потом в 8. Потом в 9 и т.д. Почему так происходит?

Comment: `Task.Run` лучше использовать вместо `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Не конкретно здесь, а вообще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` отправляет задачу `TickTimeElapsedAsync` выполняться на пул потоков (вы можете проверить это через `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`).

На пуле потоков `await Task.Delay` возвращает вас на случайный поток из пула, т. к. `SynchronizationContext` нулевой. Поэтому, да, поток каждый раз может быть новый.

---

Обратите внимание что `Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync)` возвращает `Task<Task>`: таск, задачей которого является *запустить* таск `TickTimeElapsedAsync`. Поэтому ваш `await Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync);` дожидается *запуска* таска, а не *окончания*. Если вы хотите таки дождаться окончания, используйте `await await Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync);`:

- `Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync)` возвращает запускающий таск,
- `await Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync)` возвращает его результат, то есть запущенный таск, а
- `await await Task.Factory.StartNew(TickTimeElapsedAsync)` дожидается запущенного таска.

Более «прямая» логика была бы, если воспользоваться функцией `Task.Run`: `await Task.Run(TickTimeElapsedAsync)` таки дожидается запущенного таска.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Stephen Toub, *Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы метод TickTimeElapsedAsync просто работал.  Запустился и ничего не ожидал и не возвращал. Программа пошла дальше.

Comment: @MRXIT: Тогда можно просто `TickTimeElapsedAsync();` без всяких `await`. Или если хотите на пуле потоков, то `Task.Run(TickTimeElapsedAsync);` опять-таки без `await`.

Comment: @MRXIT если вы не ожидаете асинхронную задачу, при возникновении исключения в ней, вы его никогда не увидите. Это стоит учитывать. Но да, здесь даже `async void` в таком случае подойдет.